# how to start flask_socketio app with ssl?

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio, eventlet

How should I translate app.run() to sockio.run() with SSL?

I have below app start code to run with flask development server

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(ssl_context=(ssl_cert, ssl_key))
```

I am now trying to start it with socketio like below

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True)
```

However, I cannot figure out how to pass cert into this call.
What do I have to do to make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was having the same issue. This is equivalent to what worked for me.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port="80", debug=True, ssl_context=('cert.pem', 'key.pem'))
```

For some reason I had to manually enter the server address in a web browser ( i.e. `https://127.0.0.1:5000/` )  before my angular app was able to access the flask socketio https server, but I think that is a client side issue I need to work out.

Answer (score 5):

Old question but I'll give an answer anyway.  Try something like this:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True, keyfile='key.pem', certfile='cert.pem')
```

Comment: this didn't work for me `TypeError: run_simple() got an unexpected keyword argument 'keyfile'`