# How do i run a flask_socketio application with ssl enabled?

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

Hello im trying to run a flask_socketio application with ssl.

The Code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port="80", debug=True, ssl_context=context)
```

The Error:

```
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 102-422-495
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask_socketio/__init__.py", line 580, in run_server
    eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet_socket, app,
TypeError: server() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ssl_context'
```

I already tried possible Solutions that were suggested under [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62170010/how-to-start-flask-socketio-app-with-ssl) question.

However, I cannot figure out how to pass cert into this call.
What do I have to do to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a question that applies to the web server that you are using, not to Flask-SocketIO.

Based on your error, you are using the Eventlet web server, which takes `certfile` and `keyfile` arguments ([documentation](https://eventlet.net/doc/modules/wsgi.html?highlight=wsgi#ssl)).

Add these arguments to the `socketio.run()` function and Flask-SocketIO will send them to Eventlet.

Example:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port="80", debug=True,
                 certfile='cert.pem', keyfile='key.pem',
                 server_side=True)
```